# Specifying two-level Random Effect model with rma.mv in metafor

Tags: r, meta-analysis, metafor

I am having some trouble understanding rma.mv in R which I would like to use for my first meta-analysis. I have got about 40 studies where I can extract multiple effect sizes from e.g. because they give measures for different valleys or different interventions to compare to a controll group. Because these effect measures from the same study are probably more similar than others and correlated/not independent, I want to use a study-specific random effect (specifying the random argument random = ~ 1| ID_study).

This two-level random effect is something my professor told me to do after I had read about three-level models (thinking of random = ~ 1| ID_Study/ID_ES). She said that random effect model would be enough and could keep it less complex. As I was looking for papers to cite in my method section in my thesis, I came across authors like Cheung (2019) saying that a random effect model could not account for dependency of effect sizes i.e. I believe that the “Random Effect model” described with rma.mv (https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/rma.mv.html) must be something different? Does a Random effect model with rma.mv have a different name or is described by an author somewhere (unfortunately Viechtbauer does not describe it in his metafor paper from 2010)?

Additionally I am not sure how to interpret the sigma^2 and Q-heterogeneity statistics in my case. Would sigma^2 be the same as tau = describing the heterogeneity between the studies or between the effect sizes?

Thank you very much for your much needed help in advance!

Cited papers:
Cheung, Mike W-L (2019): A Guide to Conducting a Meta-Analysis with Non-Independent Effect Sizes. In: Neuropsychol Rev 29 (4), S. 387–396. DOI: 10.1007/s11065-019-09415-6.

Viechtbauer, Wolfgang (2010): Conducting Meta-Analyses in R with the metafor Package. In: Journal of Statistical Software (36).

Comment: Some of the references https://metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I already had a look here but could not find much on rma.mv, do you have a certain reference in mind?